# What claims and what Theorem we can prove using density property in Topology and functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, density-function

From [wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set)  simple definition of dense set defined as ,In topology and related areas of mathematics, A subset A of a topological space X is called dense in X if every point x in X either belongs to A or is a limit point of A; that is, the closure of A is constituting the whole set X , the notion of density is widely useful in probability and physics and all branche of mathematics particulary Topology and functional analysis , Now my question here is : What claims and what theorem we can prove in topology and functional analysis using density property and why it's important ?

What claims and what Theorem we can prove using density property in Topology ?

Comment: The Baire Category Theorem!

Comment: I'm no expert in topology, hence commenting rather than answering. But perhaps this is useful: the discussion of covering space actions on pp. 72-73 of http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf makes explicit use of a density argument.

Comment: @dafinguzman Isn't the Baire category theorem within Functional Analysis, whereas the OP is concerned primarily with topology?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, and I don't think it can be given a clear answer unless you narrow your parameters. But, generally speaking, density is useful in large part because given a topological space $X$, there might be a dense subset $S$ of $X$, where the objects in $S$ have nice properties whereas not all the objects in $X$ have such nice properties. We can work indirectly with the not-so-nice objects in $X$ by selecting a sufficiently close approximation in $S$ which has the nice properties we desire.

Comment: @bounceback As far as I can see, the title asks about both topology and functional analysis.

Comment: I go along with the Baire Category Theorem and particularly like the book by Boas "A Primer of Real Functions" because of the applications he gives. I gave this in an undergraduate course, omitting the proof, but explaining applications. There are books which do the opposite!